# Using a Windows Keyboard with a MacBook… and TeamViewer

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout, synergy, teamviewer

I have what appears to be a rather unique problem:

I do all of my work on my MacBookPro because it's very powerful. However, since I commute to and from school by bicycle, I don't want to risk carrying my macbook in a backpack (what if I fall and the MBP dies?). As a result, I use a very low power machine (mid range Pentium4) at home as a thin TeamViewer client, though which I connect to my MBP.

Also, while at school, for ergonomic reasons, I use an external keyboard (wireless) and monitor. [This external keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004MF11MU) is a Windows keyboard, so I need some way to remap <kbd>alt</kbd> on my external keyboard to <kbd>⌘</kbd> and vice-versa.

To this end, I tried using [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/). While this was a very useful application, it had the nasty side effect of remapping the keys on my MBP's native keyboard as well. Further, I lose the remapping when I connected from my TeamViewer client at home and am forced to use the windows key when I want <kbd>⌘</kbd>.

So I switched to [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/). While this required a lot of configuration (and I mean a LOT), which I'm not opposed to, it turned out to be very flaky and decided to remap my mouse when I configured it not to (the same config would change its mind on whether to remap my mouse within 5 minutes). So this turned out to be a no-go.

A friend then told me that [synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) is highly configurable, so I'm trying it out, but I don't seem to be able to remap keys on the synergy server (my MBP). Further, I don't know if remapping the keys on the external keyboard will remap the keys on the native keyboard. Also, I will have to do some really weird hackery to get it to work correctly when I connect from home using TeamViewer.

I tried setting up my MBP as the synergy server with the following config file, but that didn't seem to work:

```
section: screens
    cortana.local:
        alt = meta
        meta = alt
end
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teamview is already attempting to map the keyboard so it is expecting your mapping to be untouched.  If you are using **KeyRemap4MacBook** you what to make the styles mapping selected explicitly exclude `TEAMVIEWER` so you don't get a double mapping situation.

If you need custom key mapping for this scenario using [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) PC to Mac styles you can find a great post here:

[**PC to Mac Switch – Don’t Relearn Your Keyboard Shortcuts**](http://blog.iteedee.com/2014/01/pc-to-mac-switch-dont-relearn-your-keyboard-shortcuts/)

Also, setting up KeyRemap4MacBook to have multiple mapping profiles is very handy as well.

Comment: KeyRemap4MacBook is now called [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/).

Answer (score 2):

System Preferences should allow choosing different modifier key mappings for each keyboard:

[image]

I have used settings like this with [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) with no issues:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <devicevendordef>
    <vendorname>KINESIS</vendorname>
    <vendorid>0x05f3</vendorid>
  </devicevendordef>
  <deviceproductdef>
    <productname>ADVANTAGE</productname>
    <productid>0x0007</productid>
  </deviceproductdef>
  <item>
    <name>kinesis</name>
    <identifier>kinesis</identifier>
    <device_only>DeviceVendor::KINESIS, DeviceProduct::ADVANTAGE</device_only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::OPTION_R</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::COMMAND_R</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

You could also try using [ControllerMate](http://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/).

Comment: Did NOT know that the built-in mapper had settings for different keyboards. Thank you!!